# Prefix selected in voiceover pronunciation when value selected from dropdown

Tags: html, macos, accessibility, dropdown, voiceover

I am using change language drop-down in my web-application, I am working on accessibility of web-application, while working on accessibility I discovered that when particular option is selected from dropdown voiceover just pronounces the selected option,but inorder to make it more accessible I wanted to pronounce it as value selected. Is it possible to prefix text 'selected' in voiceover / screen reader pronunciation?

Please find the code below

```
<label for="lang">Choose Language:</label>
 <select name="lang" id="lang">
  <option>English</option>
  <option>日本人</option>
  <option>русский</option>
  <option>中文</option>
 </select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is once more the famous question "How do I make the screen reader to speak X instead of Y ?"

The general answer is, if you want Y be spoken instead of X, then just write Y and not X. If it isn't appropriate to write Y, why should it be to speak Y?
Why a scren reader should speak something different than what's written?

I won't make the whole discussion here again, but except in relatively rare cases, things shoult be spoken as they are written. If it isn't the case, you may create problems for several ranges of people: partially sighted people who rely in both speech and written text won't hear and see the same; it's unclear if braillists should read X or Y depending on how far you consider braille as being as writing system per ce; etc.

As the name says, a **screen reader** is there to read **what is written on the screen**.
For all the rest, important information not really written directly on screen, like the fact that an item is selected or not, all screen readers have adopted different strategies and often they are configurable.
For example, the word "selected" might be said before or after the selected element; a different voice might be used; the pitch might be made lower or higher; A sound might replace the word "selected" altogether; etc.

The best is to not interfere in any way with how  exactly that kind of information is given to the user.
By interfering, you might clarify things for one specific group of users, but confuse all others.

In the case of selection in a combo box, just use the selected attribute appropriately, or maybe aria-selected for custom components, in order to mark the selection properly.
From there, leave screen readers report selection to the user as they are used to do it. Don't do anything special.